# In-App Purchases test

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, testing, in-app-purchase

I want to help my friend to test in-app purchases. He is a developer, he has the Game on his Developer Account, and he gave me the source code to integrate in-app purchases... I created product ids, and set up the code, everything is exactly how should be, i'm a developer too.

my question is: How can I test in-app purchase, if the game is on his account?

I see only 2 options: 
 1. To ask him to transfer the app into my account, and i will be able to test without any problems
 2. Ask him to give me his apple id and password of his developer account, and add it on my XCode.

Please let me know if there are any options, or what certificate i need from him to test in-app purchase.

Comment: check this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/TestingInAppPurchases.html you can create test account for testing purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He needs to invite you into his developer account.  Then setup your profiles etc for his App ID and use them in the code signing process.  You will then be a member of "his" team.  You still have your own account and he has his.

It's all done in the member center.
https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action

Comment: Note on this: You only see the menu option for "People" in Member Center if your account is a Business account or Enterprise.  If you setup as a personal developer, you have to contact Apple in order to change your account type.

Answer (score 0):

Your fiend can invite you to join his developer account as admin or 
developer. Once you accept that invitation with your developer account, you can create or delete TestUser and also In App Purchase product with your developer account login.

You will find guideline for same on developer account.

Hope this help.